# How to get a DOM element from the controller doing Stripe Integration?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

Hi I'm trying to implement Stripe example in an AngularJS application, I have a initializer that calls a function named `initStripe();` this works equal to the Stripe example:

```
function initStripe()
{
    $scope.stripe = Stripe('pk_test_6pRNasdwwehFeQd4XMUh');
    $scope.elements = $scope.stripe.elements();
    $scope.style = {
        base: {
            color: '#32325d',
            lineHeight: '18px',
            fontFamily: '"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif',
            fontSmoothing: 'antialiased',
            fontSize: '16px',
            '::placeholder': {
                color: '#aab7c4'
            }
        },
        invalid: {
            color: '#fa755a',
            iconColor: '#fa755a'
        }
    };

    $scope.card = $scope.elements.create('card', {style: $scope.style});
    //console.log( document.getElementById('body') );
    $scope.card.mount('#card-element');
}
```

The problem is in the last instruction `$scope.card.mount('#card-element');`, here I get this error:

> The selector you specified (`#card-element`) applies to no DOM
>   elements that are currently on the page.

Doing tests I can check that moving the HTML code of position works, but not works in the div I need.

```
<body>
<!-- here works -->
   <div ng-if="currentStep == 3">
    <!-- here doesn't works -->
   </div>
</body>
```

The HTML is the same of the Stripe website example:

https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/quickstart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, there are two different ways to hide and show divs in angularjs, `ng-if` and `ng-show` or `ng-hide`. If you change your `ng-if` to `ng-show`, the logic can remain the same, but it should work. Explanation below.

`ng-if` works by completely removing the element and any children elements from the DOM if it evaluates to false. This means any sort of element selector will fail when trying to find anything inside of an `ng-if` evaluating to false.

`ng-show` and `ng-hide` work by using `display: hide` if evaluated to be hidden. This allows you to still select them with an element selector, but hide them from being displayed.

In the problem you are seeing, it is looking for the element inside of your `ng-if`, and since your `ng-if` evaluates to false, that element is not being found.

Comment: great answer! really I knew the difference but never I think that were the reason.